# Syntax error on VBA: Trying to filter based on a cell value

Tags: excel, vba

i am trying to filter some extensive data based on a cell value using VBA, however I keep getting a syntax error all the time I put my code, I am missing something?

```
Public Sub FilterDepartment_Sales()

 Sheets("BR-L1").Range"(A8").AutoFilter Field =1, Criteria1:=Cells(1, 1).Value

   End Sub
```

Comment: `Range"(A8")` should be `Range("A8")` for starters

Comment: And `Field := 1`